# How to select a parent element in tree and not lose child's 'selected' styles

Tags: javascript, css, next.js, material-ui, treeview

I have a MUI TreeView component with a nested mapping of Categories (parent) and Articles (Child).
When I select a child, that child has styles applied to it based on "selected".
When I click a parent, the previous child loses its "selected" styles.

How can I make a differentiation between "child selected" and "parent clicked(selected)".

I would prefer to do this all in CSS if possible.
This is a Next.js app.

My CategoryItem CSS:

```
const StyledCategoryItemRoot = styled(TreeItem)(({ theme }) => ({
  [`& .${treeItemClasses.content}`]: {
    fontWeight: theme.typography.fontWeightBold,
    marginBottom: 5,
    paddingLeft: 0,
    borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
    '&.Mui-selected.Mui-focused, &:hover, &.Mui-selected:hover': {
      backgroundColor:
        theme.palette.mode === 'light'
          ? alpha('#ff9aff', 0.16)
          : alpha('#2f506f', 0.24),
    },
    '&.Mui-selected, &.Mui-focused': {
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    },
  },
}));
```

My ArticleItem CSS:

```
const StyledArticleItemRoot = styled(TreeItem)(({ theme, router, post }) => ({
  color:
    theme.palette.mode === 'light'
      ? theme.palette.grey[900]
      : theme.palette.grey[500],
  [`& .${treeItemClasses.content}`]: {
    fontWeight: theme.typography.fontWeightBold,
    paddingLeft: 0,
    borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
    transition: '.2s',
    '&.Mui-selected:hover, &.Mui-selected.Mui-focused:hover, &:hover': {
      color: theme.palette.mode === 'light' ? theme.palette.grey[800] : 'white',
    },
    '&.Mui-focused, &.Mui-selected, &.Mui-selected.Mui-focused': {
      backgroundColor:
        theme.palette.mode === 'light'
          ? alpha('#ff9aff', 0.16)
          : alpha('#2f506f', 0.16),
      color:
        post.attributes.slug !== router.query.slug
          ? theme.palette.grey[500]
          : theme.palette.mode === 'light'
          ? theme.palette.primary.main
          : theme.palette.secondary.main,
    },
  },
}));
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to prevent Categories from being selectable?

Comment: I want to be able to click the Categories dropdown without losing the "selected" styling on Article. When article is "selected" style={{ color:{color} background:{background}}}, when I click a Categories, Article's color reverts to the "not-selected" style. Working example check out sidebar functionality of https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/installation/ . Example of what mine does right now (more or less) check out "Gmail clone" here: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-tree-view/#main-content

Comment: That's because the Article is no longer selected at that point. The Category is selected instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in MUI tree view component ,if multiselect is off `multiSelect={false}`
you can only select one node (parent or child), you can't selected both parent and child at same time!

so if you selected child node then selected parent node , the child will **lose selected node style** because it is **not selected** anymore !

**Answering ur question in comments** :

> I want to be able to click the Categories dropdown without losing the "selected" styling on Article.

what u can do this by:
handling selection of nodes manually

```
<TreeView
   aria-label="file system navigator"
   key="treeView"
   defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
   defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
   multiSelect={false}
   selected={selectedNodes}
   onNodeSelect={(e, node_ids) => {
     handleClick(e, node_ids);
   }}> //add here tree nodes 
</TreeView>
```

NOW in handleClick function , you will set the selected nodes :

```
setSelectedNodes(nodes_ids);
```

AND to make it **ONLY** selected if the clicked element is the node label and **NOT the dropdown NOR the collapsable icon**

so the handleClick will look like this :

```
 function handleClick(e, nodes_ids) {
  if (e.target.className == "MuiTreeItem-label") 
   setSelectedNodes(nodes_ids);
}
```

**ps** : don't forget to add selectedNodes to ur state :

```
[selectedNodes, setSelectedNodes]=useState([]);
```

Comment: I've sense figured out how to fix my problem using CSS, but this would have worked aswell. thank you for this explicit answer